# In VS Code, why does 'SFDX: Update Checkpoints in Org' fail with 'Checkpoints can be set on valid line of Apex source. Invalid checkpoint location'

Tags: vs-code, checkpoint

When running

```
SFDX: Update Checkpoints in Org
```

using Salesforce Extensions for Visual Studio Code I get the error

```
Checkpoints can be set on valid line of Apex source. Invalid checkpoint location
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was a space character in the path to my project, e.g.

```
My Projects/Project1
```

I removed the space in the path and was able to successfully update checkpoints.

Special characters cause same issue, e.g.

```
R&D/Project
```

To resolve, I would suggest to first close the folder in VS Code, edit folder name outside of VS Code, then open renamed folder in VS Code.

Thanks to this post for resolution
https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1476

Comment: I have the same probem as OP but this wasn't the solution for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is your checkpoint on a line that performs some action, e.g. modifies a variable?
If the checkpoint is on a method declaration line then you will get the error.

Comment: It was on a method call line.

Comment: @mjaggard check to see if your package paths defined in sfdx-project.json start with a `./` rather than just the root folder name. Even though these two are equivalent locations, having the leading `./` was causing this problem for me:  `"path": "./src/common/utils"`  vs.  `"path": "src/common/utils"`.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for the problem that I was encountering, hope this helps someone who is struggling with the same: I have a folder path that contains `OneDrive` (company enforced) and it has special characters in it. I had to create a different folder to bypass this and make the path look more simple.  For eg: `c://myname/Myfolder`

This worked for me !!

Answer (score 0):

This will happen to me occasionally when my `.sf` or `.sfdx` files are corrupted.

Trashing these folders inside the offending project and reopening VS Code will resolve the issue.

A dead giveaway is that it will complain about a failure on a line that *should not* have any issue creating a checkpoint (a true valid line).